# vhosts configuration grabs conf files in alphabetical order

Tags: apache, vhosts

So I had an interesting and somewhat perplexing issue pop up on me that I hope someone can answer. We have several sites hosted on an amazon server at aws. I was launching a new site and configured the vhost config file. It just so happened that it was highest on the list alphabetically. The issue is that it basically overrode the other vhosts and all the sites now pointed to the root directory of the site I just launched.

My question is a two part, how do I prevent this from happening again? Second part, why didn't the one previously first in the directory alphabetically not override the others in the same directory? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the configurations? Without seeing them, it's hard to tell what's going on.